# Get facebook faces using the graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to make a facebook box on my website, with a custom Like button to like our facebook page. And in text a line like: 8763 people like our facebook page. I can build both these using the graph api and `json_decode()`.

But is it also possible to get 10 pictures of the people who liked my page? It's something the designer brewed up, and Im told to just make this. :)

Gr.

Comment: paste graph api response

Answer (score 1):

Not possible in a straightforward way, only friends of the current authenticated user.

`SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND page_id = "xxxx"`

You could look into grabbing the ids from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#conversations hold them in array with only unique ids up until 10.

Also http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php

> We permit the Facebook Like Button logo to be used in connection with the Like button social plugin, which enables users to make connections to your pages and share content back to their friends on Facebook with one click. We also permit use of the Facebook Like Button in offline advertising (e.g., print advertising) to reference and direct people to your Facebook Page or your website that has the Like Button social plugin implemented. We do not allow the use of the Like Button logo in online advertising. Please see the Usage section below for more information.

Which to means you cannot have custom Like boxes or buttons, so be sure you are not breaking policy

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the user ids, then it’ll be really simple – see “picture” connection on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/